# Общие элементы двух массивов

Tags: python, массивы

Код не работает:
"IndexError: list index out of range"

```
def kon(arr1,arr2):
    array=[]
    for i in range(len(arr2)):
        for j in range(len(arr1)):
            if arr1[j]==arr2[i]:
                array.append(arr1[j])
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        for j in range(len(arr2)):
            if arr2[j]==arr1[i]:
                array.append(arr2[j])
    array=sorted(array)
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        while array[i]==array[i+1]:
            del array[i]
    return array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `del array[i]` уменьшает длину массива, поэтому возникает обращение к несуществующему элементу: i осталось прежнее, а длина стала меньше.

Кроме того не понятно зачем второй цикл. Вы же ищете общие элементы и проверили все вхождения элементов из arr1 в arr2. Собственно других общих нет.

Вот такой код на Питоне будет более правильным:

```
def intersection(arr1,arr2):
    array=[]
    for element in arr1:
        if element in arr2:
            array.append(element)
    return array

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,3,4,2]

print(intersection(a,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(array)-1):
    while array[i]==array[i+1]:
        del array[i]
```

Диапазон значений `i` вычисляется один раз - до начала итераций. А внутри цикла Вы удаляете элементы массива, то есть укорачиваете его.